# Flaw in my reasoning for the maximum of $ab$ if $a,b\ge0$ and $a+2b=3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, solution-verification

Problem statement: What is the maximum value of the product $ab$ if $a$,$b$ are non-negative numbers such that $a+2b=3$?

What is the flaw in my solution?

We know that $\sqrt{ab} ≤ \frac{ (a+b)}{2}$ and that $a=3-2b$. The product $ab$ will be maximum when it is equal to the square of the RHS of the inequality above. Plugging in for $a$, and squaring both sides we get the equation: $(3-2b)(b)=\frac{(((3-2b)+b)^2}{4}$. Which gives $b=1$. And plugging $b=1$ into the the equation in the problem statement gives $a=1$. So, the max product is $1*1=1$.

What am I doing wrong? What concepts could I be I misunderstanding? Can you please explain? The actual answer is $9/8$. Thank you.

Comment: The right-hand side of your inequality depends on $b$. You can't claim a maximum based on a bound that depends on the variable being optimized.

Comment: Maybe that is really intuitive and obvious to you and many others, but I just don’t see why. Anything anyone can do to help me grasp this?

Comment: "*The product ab will be maximum when it is equal to the square of the RHS of the inequality above*" — The equality case of the AM-GM inequality is always $a=b$, but this doesn't tell you that $(a+b)^2/4$ is the maximum of $ab$ when $a$ and $b$ vary under other constraints. Try for example to apply the same argument to "*what is the maximum value of the product $ab$ if $a$, $b$ are non-negative numbers such that $a=3$*".

Comment: Please carefully spell out the steps that you believe justify the sentence:  "The product $ab$ will be maximum when it is equal to the square of the RHS of the inequality above."  Because that sentence is not, in fact, correct.

Comment: @dxiv in your first comment do you want to say that we cannot give maximum value unless we have a constant term on RHS

Comment: @lalittolani If it's not a constant relative to the constraints, then how can you claim it is a maximum? Compare the difference in my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed: We have $$(3-2b)b \le\frac{(3-b)^2}{4}$$ is a true statement and in fact equality holds when $b=1$.

However, it is possibel for the LHS to get a larger value and the equality doesn't hold.

To maximize it notice that $(3-2b)b$ is a concave quadratic and the optimal value is attained when $$b = \frac{1.5}{2}=\frac34$$

That is the maximum value is $\left( \frac32\right) \cdot \left( \frac34\right)=\frac98.$

[image]

Comment: sir you graphically proved it that " it is possibel for the LHS to get a larger value and the equality doesn't hold" but how we can say that analytically

Comment: to show something is possible, we just need an example. we can use the example, in this question and find the maximum value of the quadratic curve and verify the RHS forms a strict upper bound.

Comment: @lalittolani You could prove that by showing that $3x-2x^2$ intersects with $(3-x)^2/4$ at 1, but the former has a peak that is higher: $3\cdot 0.75-2\cdot 0.75^2=1.125$.

Answer (score 4):

Building upon OP's attempt to use AM-GM, the following will work, instead, because it is arranged such that the right-hand side of the inequality matches the known constant sum.

$$
\sqrt{a \cdot 2b} \le \frac{a + 2b}{2}=\frac{3}{2} \;\implies\; 2ab \le \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{9}{4} \;\implies\; ab \le \frac{9}{8}
$$

The maximum value of $\frac{9}{8}$ is attained when $a = 2b$, which is $a=\frac{3}{2}, b=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Comment: I think somebody has a grudge because it looks like all the others got one (though I can't really tell that about Siong's answer since it has gained a few more points than when I saw this).

Answer (score 0):

I know you have accepted the answer but still I have one analogy to share with you-

Suppose we have a quadratic equation(to say) as -

$e^xx^2-(logx)x+3=0$

Now you found it's roots by using quadratic formula. The "expression" of roots that you will obtain will also be some function of $x$ and in that case you can't call those expressions as roots because roots are the values of variable for which the equation reduces to zero and you can't get values of variable in terms of variable because a value is fixed. If the equation would be as follows-

$x^2-3x+2=0$ then the you will obtain a constant value and in that case you can say that those values are certainly the roots of your equation.

Similarly ,as @dxiv mentioned in his answer and comments, "unless you claim it is a constant relative to constraints, you can't claim it a maximum".